# Invalid Block Tag, Expected 'endblock'

Tags: python, django

I know this issue is all over stackoverflow, but this particular instance of it has me lost. The reason is, I get this error periodically - without changing the HTML file at all.

The issue seems to be here:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% load support_tags %}

{% block content_header %}
<h1>Header</h1>
{% endblock content_header %}

{% block new-main-area %}
        {% ticket_categories as categories %} {# Problem is here #}
            <option value="None">Select a Category</option>
        {% for cat in categories %}
            <option value="{{cat.slug}}">{{cat}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
{% endblock new-main-area %}

{% block extrascripts_bottom %}
{% endblock extrascripts_bottom %}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO, the code is misusing `with` tag:

Replace following lines:

```
{% ticket_categories as categories %} <!-- Problem is here -->
    <option value="None">Select a Category</option>
{% for cat in categories %}
    <option value="{{cat.slug}}">{{cat}}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

with:

```
{% with ticket_categories as categories %} <!-- Problem is here -->
    <option value="None">Select a Category</option>
{% for cat in categories %}
    <option value="{{cat.slug}}">{{cat}}</option>
{% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```

Or (`with` is not necessary at all):

```
<option value="None">Select a Category</option>
{% for cat in ticket_categories %}
    <option value="{{cat.slug}}">{{cat}}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That totally worked (both of them). Thank you very much! I must have just missed that 'with' portion of the syntax.